# Slider Script not working properly when integrated with asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was working on a slider with has contents, Images & thumbnails also.  SO i started working on [following script](http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/LOF-Slider/demo2.html) which is working fine.

Now i want to integrate same script in asp.net website with contents coming from database.

my asp.net slider started to give me all sorts of problem finally managed to fix most of it except the one i am facing I have create HTML File from asp.net webpage output for your reference [here](http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/TEST.HTML)

It is almost same code what is in the working example i am not able to figure out why slider is not working on [TEST.HTML](http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/TEST.HTML) page.

http://jsfiddle.net/WGqbb/

**This Question has been resolve, Problem was in HTML markup.**

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1"><title>

</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><link href="../styles/english_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
<body id="body"  dir="ltr">
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx?language=en-us&amp;issue=5" id="frmMasterPage">


    <script src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/scripts/slider/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>              
    <script src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/scripts/slider/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/scripts/slider/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/styles/slider-en.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var buttons = { previous: $('#jslidernews2 .button-previous'),
            next: $('#jslidernews2 .button-next')
        };
        $('#jslidernews2').lofJSidernews({ interval: 5000,
            direction: 'opacity', // for fading effect
            easing: 'linear', // for fading effect
            //easing:'easeInOutQuad',  // for transition effect
            duration: 1200,
            auto: true,
            mainWidth: 590,
            mainHeight: 300,
            navigatorHeight: 76,
            navigatorWidth: 160,
            maxItemDisplay: 4,
            buttons: buttons
        });
    });

</script>
<style>

    ul.lof-main-wapper li {
        position:relative;    
    }
</style>



 <div id="jslidernews2" class="lof-slidecontent" style="width:750px; height:300px;">

            <div  class="button-previous">Previous</div>

             <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->



                    <div class="main-slider-content" style="width:590px; height:300px; float:right;">
                        <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                            <li>
                                   <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/94618045-044c-4977-a5d7-bf2a44f19f1e.png" />      
                                  <div class="slider-description">
                                    <h4>Sheikh Mohammed holds fast to his father’s le...</h4>
                                    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                                 </div>
                            </li>

                          </ul>      
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-slider-content" style="width:590px; height:300px; float:right;">
                        <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                            <li>
                                   <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/5daed017-e3aa-49d8-b477-ce607dfcbd51.png" />      
                                  <div class="slider-description">
                                    <h4>It’s time the Lebanese removed their shackles...</h4>
                                    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                                 </div>
                            </li>

                          </ul>      
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-slider-content" style="width:590px; height:300px; float:right;">
                        <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                            <li>
                                   <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/d158c479-6559-46c9-bae7-e7e04a1cbf9b.png" />      
                                  <div class="slider-description">
                                    <h4>Belarus is open for business</h4>
                                    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                                 </div>
                            </li>

                          </ul>      
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-slider-content" style="width:590px; height:300px; float:right;">
                        <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                            <li>
                                   <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/de155ceb-c148-495b-9aa0-ad1f9f0f463c.png" />      
                                  <div class="slider-description">
                                    <h4>A Royal Visit</h4>
                                    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                                 </div>
                            </li>

                          </ul>      
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-slider-content" style="width:590px; height:300px; float:right;">
                        <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                            <li>
                                   <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/ff435532-635a-4089-b7e3-858a305cbfed.png" />      
                                  <div class="slider-description">
                                    <h4>Building Dubai together</h4>
                                    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                                 </div>
                            </li>

                          </ul>      
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-slider-content" style="width:590px; height:300px; float:right;">
                        <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                            <li>
                                   <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/5a2d74a8-5ce8-4816-895b-7235ac2b3081.png" />      
                                  <div class="slider-description">
                                    <h4>Two new debuts from Mitsubishi</h4>
                                    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                                 </div>
                            </li>

                          </ul>      
                    </div>


                           <div class="navigator-content">
                              <div class="navigator-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="navigator-wrap-inner">
                                      <li>
                                            <div>
                                            <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/94618045-044c-4977-a5d7-bf2a44f19f1e.png" />
                                            </div>    
                                        </li>              

                                    </ul>
                              </div>

                         </div>

                           <div class="navigator-content">
                              <div class="navigator-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="navigator-wrap-inner">
                                      <li>
                                            <div>
                                            <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/5daed017-e3aa-49d8-b477-ce607dfcbd51.png" />
                                            </div>    
                                        </li>              

                                    </ul>
                              </div>

                         </div>

                           <div class="navigator-content">
                              <div class="navigator-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="navigator-wrap-inner">
                                      <li>
                                            <div>
                                            <img src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/d158c479-6559-46c9-bae7-e7e04a1cbf9b.png" />
                                            </div>    
                                        </li>              

                                    </ul>
                              </div>

                         </div>

                           <div class="navigator-content">
                              <div class="navigator-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="navigator-wrap-inner">
                                      <li>
                                            <div>
                                            <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/de155ceb-c148-495b-9aa0-ad1f9f0f463c.png" />
                                            </div>    
                                        </li>              

                                    </ul>
                              </div>

                         </div>

                           <div class="navigator-content">
                              <div class="navigator-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="navigator-wrap-inner">
                                      <li>
                                            <div>
                                            <img  src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/ff435532-635a-4089-b7e3-858a305cbfed.png" />
                                            </div>    
                                        </li>              

                                    </ul>
                              </div>

                         </div>

                           <div class="navigator-content">
                              <div class="navigator-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="navigator-wrap-inner">
                                      <li>
                                            <div>
                                            <img src="http://demo.kashmirsouq.com/images/article/5a2d74a8-5ce8-4816-895b-7235ac2b3081.png" />
                                            </div>    
                                        </li>              

                                    </ul>
                              </div>

                         </div>

          <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
          <div class="button-next">Next</div>

          <!-- BUTTON PLAY-STOP -->
          <div class="button-control"><span></span></div>
          <!-- END OF BUTTON PLAY-STOP -->

 </div>



        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the first link (demo2.html) doesn't load. The test.html page contains six 404 errors. It's not really clear what's the error.

Comment: From what i see, it seems like the html schema are not the same. In the demo, the main pictures are in a <ul> and in your test they are all in <div>.

Comment: There are some files that are not loading, like the engine_css.css and a lot of images. This is a question that you ask from us to debug your code. What you should do is to open your browser debug tools to see whats going wrong.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddler version also.

Comment: @Nir:, I check all 4 link i have mentioned are working i have cross checked it

Comment: `english_css.css` CSS is not for the slider it is used by the template so no need for this

Comment: @Aristos:, JsFiddler version show all the image, may be server is slow that is why it may not be showing all the images

Comment: I see that you have only one menu or the left and many images on the right.

Comment: @Aristos:, I have resolved the issue i was looping through at wrong place which was generating wrong HTML..

Answer (score 0):

It was exactly what i had told you.

Your html markup was incorrectly set up. You had placed all your images inside their own `<div><ul>`

i fixed your mark up to be in one `<div>` and one `<ul>` and the images in their own `<li>`

http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/WGqbb/1/